# extract data from a file in shell script

Tags: shell

I have lots of data in a file like as below

```
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test1"; sid:16521; rev:1;created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2016_07_01;)
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test2"; nocase; distance:0; sid:16521; rev:1;created_at 2010_10_30, updated_at 2013_07_11;)
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test3"; file_data; content:"clsid"; nocase; distance:0; created_at 2008_08_03, updated_at 2016_05_01;
```

Comment: It's generally helpful not to describe just what you're already using, but how it fails / in what respect it still needs work. Otherwise, there's not actually an explicit *question* here.

Comment: BTW, `grep '^alert'` makes `grep -v ^#` moot -- a line can't start with `alert` and *also* start with `#`, after all. (Also, combining `awk` and `grep` or `sed` is redundant -- `awk` can do everything `sed` or `grep` can)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extracting fields from a file in Shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910876/extracting-fields-from-a-file-in-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sh
sed -re 's/^.*created_at ([0-9_]+).*updated_at ([0-9_]+).*$/\1, \2/' input.txt
```

For `input.txt`:

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test1"; sid:16521; rev:1;created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2016_07_01;)
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test2"; nocase; distance:0; sid:16521; rev:1;created_at 2010_10_30, updated_at 2013_07_11;)
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test3"; file_data; content:"clsid"; nocase; distance:0; created_at 2008_08_03, updated_at 2016_05_01;
```

Output:

```
2010_07_30, 2016_07_01
2010_10_30, 2013_07_11
2008_08_03, 2016_05_01
```

---

A more step-by-step approach might look like this:

```sh
cat input.txt \
    | grep -Eo '(created|updated)_at [0-9_]+' \
    | cut -d ' ' -f 2 \
    | sed 'N;s/\n/, /'
```

Here we are using `grep` to output only the data that matches the given regex, `(created|updated)_at [0-9_]+`:

- `(created|updated)_at` - match either the text 'created_at' or the text 'updated_at'
- followed immediately by one space, and then multiple characters from the group: `0123456789_`

Interim output:

```
created_at 2010_07_30
updated_at 2016_07_01
created_at 2010_10_30
updated_at 2013_07_11
created_at 2008_08_03
updated_at 2016_05_01
```

`cut` is then used to take only the second field (`-f 2`), delimited by a space (`-d ' '`).

Output:

```
2010_07_30
2016_07_01
2010_10_30
2013_07_11
2008_08_03
2016_05_01
```

Finally, `sed` is used to join every two lines together (`N`), and replacing the newline with a comma space (`s/\n/, /`).

Output:

```
2010_07_30, 2016_07_01
2010_10_30, 2013_07_11
2008_08_03, 2016_05_01
```

Comment: If you're trying to represent best practices here, might want to dump the UUOC.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've updated the first example, didn't want to overly confuse the OP.

Answer (score 0):

awk can do it a little simpler:

```
awk 'NF{gsub(/[;)]/,"");print $(NF-2),$NF}' file
```

NF - so we only act on fields with data

gsub - to get rid of some guff on the last item

print third last and last items