# extracting fields from a file in Shell

Tags: shell, awk

I have lots of data in a file like as below

```
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test1"; sid:16521; rev:1;created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2016_07_01;)
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test2"; nocase; sid :23476;distance:0; rev:1;created_at 2010_10_30, updated_at 2013_07_11;)
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test3"; sid:236487; file_data; content:"clsid"; nocase; distance:0; created_at 2008_08_03, updated_at 2016_05_01;
```

I want to extract sid,msg,created_at and updated_at from the file & output should looks like

```
test1 | 16521 | 2010_07_30 | 2016_07_01
test2 | 23476 | 2010_10_30 | 2013_07_11
test3 | 236487| 2008_08_03 | 2016_05_01
```

and the script which i used is

```
cat $file  | grep -v "^#" | grep "^alert" | sed 's/\"//g' | awk -F ';' '
{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    {
            if (match($i,"sid:")>0)
        {
            split($i, array1, ":")
            Rule_sid=array1[2]
                    }
            if(match($i,"msg:")>0)
                    {
                        split($i, array, "(")
            split(array[2], array2, ":")
                        message=array2[2]
                    }
            if(match($i,/metadata:/)>0 )
        {
            split($i, array3,/created_at/)
            create_date=array3[2]
        }
            if(match($i,/metadata:/)>0 )
                    {
                        split($i, array4, ", updated_at ")
            update_date=array4[2]
                    }


           }
            print Rule_sid "|" message "|" create_date "|" update_date
    }' >> Rule_Files/$file
```

Comment: So you provided code that you tried. What went wrong with it? What is different between what it output and what you wanted?

Comment: I'm not able to extract created_at & updated_at properly like as above

Comment: sorry,i have made the all required changes

Comment: So unlike the rest of the fields, there are no colons after `created_at` and `updated_at`?

Comment: yes,there is no colons between created_at and updated_at like rest of fields.

Comment: Where did the post go?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you can extract the fields with a regex using `sed`:

```
sed '/^alert/s/^.*msg[: ]*"\([^"]*\)".*sid[: ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\);.*created_at *\([^,]*\),.*updated_at *\([0-9_][0-9_]*\).*$/\1|\2|\3|\4/' $file
```

Which gives you output like this:

```
test1|16521|2010_07_30|2016_07_01
test2|23476|2010_10_30|2013_07_11
test3|236487|2008_08_03|2016_05_01
```

Now you want that nicely lined up into columns, you'll have to feed it to something else, perhaps awk:

```
sed '/^alert/s/^.*msg[: ]*"\([^"]*\)".*sid[: ]*\([0-9][0-9]*\);.*created_at *\([^,]*\),.*updated_at *\([0-9_][0-9_]*\).*$/\1|\2|\3|\4/' $file |
awk -F\|  'BEGIN { OFS="| " } {$2=sprintf("%6d",$2)}1'
```

Which gives you this:

```
test1|  16521| 2010_07_30| 2016_07_01
test2|  23476| 2010_10_30| 2013_07_11
test3| 236487| 2008_08_03| 2016_05_01
```

If you have to deal with arbitrarily-wide column values and still want the vertical alignment, then you'll have to write something that processes all of the lines first to find the widest value of each before printing anything out. That is an exercise I leave to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

Modify `-v OFS=" | "` and  `-v extract="msg,sid,created_at,updated_at"` as per your interest, `OFS` is output field separator and variable `extract` holds list of fields (separated by comma) which need to be parsed, if any field not found it will give `Null`

Program assumes field value exists next to current field match, suppose field `sid` found when `j=4`, its value exists at `j+1` that is at `j=5`.

**Input**

```
$ cat file
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test1"; sid:16521; rev:1;created_at 2010_07_30, updated_at 2016_07_01;)
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test2"; nocase; sid :23476;distance:0; rev:1;created_at 2010_10_30, updated_at 2013_07_11;)
 alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "test3"; sid:236487; file_data; content:"clsid"; nocase; distance:0; created_at 2008_08_03, updated_at 2016_05_01;)
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -v OFS=" | " -v extract="msg,sid,created_at,updated_at" '
 BEGIN{
    split(extract,Fields,/,/)
 }
 {
    gsub(/[:";,()]/," "); 
    s=""; 
    for(i=1; i in Fields; i++)
    { 
        f = 1
        for(j=1; j<=NF; j++)
        { 
            if($j==Fields[i])
            {
              f = 0 
              s = ( s ? s OFS :"") $(j+1) 
              break 
            } 
        }
        if(f){
            s = (s ? s OFS:"") "Null"
        }     
     } 
        print s 
 }' file

test1 | 16521 | 2010_07_30 | 2016_07_01
test2 | 23476 | 2010_10_30 | 2013_07_11
test3 | 236487 | 2008_08_03 | 2016_05_01
```